# Generating a list of same lists and performing different operations on particular lists without affecting any other list in the list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have to generate a list of lists of very large size 10^5 lists each list containing (10^5) elements. Later I need to perform different operations on different lists.

for example:

I have tried

```
u=[0 for i in xrange(10^^5)]
v=[u for j in xrange(10^^5)]
```

when I tried to perform a operation for particular list it affects all the lists inside the list.

for example:

```
for x in xrange(1000):
    for y in xrange(0:100):
        v[x][y]=1
        print v
```

I want this "print v" to display something like `[[1,0,0...],[0,0,0...],[0,0,0],[]....10^^5 times]` but it happens to display  `[[1,0,0...],[1,0,0...],[1,0,0],[1,0,0....]....10^^5 times]` for all the lists inside the list(NOTE : I have not run the whole loop)

Later I have tried

```
 v=[[for j in xrange(10^^5)] for j in xrange(10^^5)]
```

And performed the operations I wanted.This worked fine but the time taken is very high. Can anyone let me know why the first case didn't work. Please also let me know efficient way of generating list of duplicate lists and perform those operations without affecting other lists

Also please let me know any other way of implementing it using libraries like numpy.

Comment: "This worked fine but the time taken is very high" - yes, because it's actually doing all the work that needs to be done, unlike your first snippet. Never compare the performance of working code and uselessly wrong code; you can do anything in constant time if you're okay with doing it uselessly wrong.

Comment: @user2357112  v=[u for j in xrange(10^^5)]  takes comparatively very less time but the performed operation on latter section does not stick to the singe list it intended to work on.May be it because all the lists are duplicates of "u" the operation is being applied to all.Can you suggest how I can confine this to particular list as I wanted it to be

Comment: The first version builds exactly two lists. `v` does not have 100000 lists in it in that version; it has the same list, 100000 times. The code that actually works is slower because building 100000 lists of 100000 elements each takes a lot of time and memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [51]: u = [0 for i in range(5)]
In [52]: u
Out[52]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
In [53]: v = [u for j in range(4)]
In [54]: v
Out[54]: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
In [55]: v[0][1]=2
In [56]: v
Out[56]: [[0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]]
```

`v` has 4 elements, each point to `u`.  Change one, and it changes all, and it changes `u` as well.

But if I use `u[:]` copy with making `w`, now each sublist of `w` is unique.  Changing one does not change the others, nor does it change `u` (or `v`):

```
In [57]: w = [u[:] for j in range(4)]
In [58]: w
Out[58]: [[0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]]
In [59]: w[0][1]=4
In [60]: w
Out[60]: [[0, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]]
In [61]: u
Out[61]: [0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Constructing `w` will be slower, and will take more memory.  But it should be faster than `[[0 for i in range(5)] for j in range(4)]`, and take up the same amount of memory.

Testing the times

```
In [62]: timeit [[0 for i in range(5)] for j in range(4)]
6.42 µs ± 99 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [63]: timeit w = [u[:] for j in range(4)]
2.24 µs ± 84.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [64]: timeit v = [u for j in range(4)]
1.23 µs ± 13.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.This really helped a lot !!